# Is there a complex Geometric Hahn Banach theorem for imaginary part?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I know the complex version of the geometric Hahn Banach theorem, e.g. in here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497406/789584

> Let $X$ be a (complex) locally convex space, and $A,B\subset X$ disjoint, nonempty, convex, with $A$ compact and $B$ closed. Then there exists a continuous linear functional $\varphi:X\to\mathbb C$  and $c,d\in\mathbb R$ with
> $$
> \text{Re}\,\varphi(v)<c<d<\text{Re}\,\varphi(w),\ \ \ v\in A,\ \ w\in B. 
> $$

I am wondering if the imaginary part of $\varphi$ above satisfy a similar relations, namely if there is $c', d'\in\mathbb R$ such that $$
\text{Im}\,\varphi(v)<c'<d'<\text{Im}\,\varphi(w),\ \ \ v\in A,\ \ w\in B. 
$$

Comment: This follows trivially! Given $\phi$, let $\psi=i\phi$; then $\Im \phi=\Re\psi$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich does it, though?  The result says that a $\varphi$ exists, so why must $i\varphi$ also admit the same properties?

Comment: I didn't say $i\phi$ "had the same properties"! It's clearly linear, by definition. And it's clear that $\Re(i\phi)=\Im\phi$.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that can't be any essential difference between taking the real and imaginary parts here. Lest there be confusion about the formal details:

The theorem says there exists $\psi\in X^*$ such that $\Re\psi$ separates $A$ and $B$ (meaning that that inequality holds). Let $\phi=i\psi$. Then $\phi\in X^*$ and $\Im\phi=\Re\psi$, so $\Im\phi$ separates $A$ and $B$, as desired.